# What term do linguists use to denote the predicate minus the arguments of the verb?

Tags: terminology

I would like a term used by linguists that stands for the predicate minus the arguments of the verb.

One possible candidate is “verb group.”   This link, http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/verb%20group, defines “verb group” as follows:

verb group  ( verb groups    plural  ) A verb group or verbal group consists of a verb, or of a main verb following a modal or one or more auxiliaries.     Examples are “walked,” “can see,” and had been waiting.”

But the latter definition doesn’t come from a linguistics source as far as I can tell.

Another possible candidate is “verb phrase.”     The SIL Linguistic Glossary site (http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAVerbPhrase.htm) gives two definitions:   a definition from traditional grammar that resembles the above definition of “verb group,” and a definition from generative grammar that is synonymous with “predicate.”

Which term would fill the bill?

Comment: I think that 'verb group' does the job just fine.

Comment: *Verb group* is possible, but whether it's the right choice depends on your theory.  Are you asking about a particular framework?

Comment: No, I'm just describing a conlang.  But if possible, I'd like to use vocabulary from "Basic Linguistic Theory," the descriptive theory used by R.M.W. Dixon.   I'll use any available term though.  Apparently, I've got a couple of choices already, "verb group" and "predicator."

Comment: In the verb group analysis, the main verb plus its auxiliaries, taken as a group, have the predicator function.  In the catenative auxiliary analysis, the first auxiliary has the predicator function, and it takes a non-finite complement, similar to the catenative *like to see*.  But *can [see]* has a bare infinitival complement, while *like [to see]* has a *to*-infinitival complement.  Other analyses are possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: [predicators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28grammar%29#Predicators). See footnote 13 for sources.
Some people call them *predicate chains*, or *verb chain*.